# What's the time complexity of using for loop to iterate 2D array?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm#answer-22688792),it said that:

> An algorithm is said to run in linear time if its time execution is directly proportional to the input size, i.e. time grows linearly as input size increases.

I have input a 3x3 array.So I need to input 9 numbers.It need 9 times to iterate.

I have input a 4x4 array.So I need to input 16 numbers.It need 16 times to iterate.

........

The execution of iteration is directly proportional to the amount of numbers(or the size).
So I think the time complexity should be `O(n)`.

But [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm#answer-33474486) said that:

> O(n^c): Time complexity of nested loops is equal to the number of times the innermost statement is executed. For example the following sample loops have O(n^2) time complexity

```
for (int i = 1; i <=n; i += c) {
   for (int j = 1; j <=n; j += c) {
      // some O(1) expressions
   }
}
```

I feel a little confused.
So I think the question can also be:

What is the mean of `n` in array?(Does it means the size of the array or the dimension of the array?)What's the time complexity of use `for` loop to iterate 2D array.
Is it `O(n)` or `O(n^2)`?

If the time complexity is `O(n^2)` due to it have two `for` loops.
I use this to create a 3x3 array:

```
a[0,1,2] -> b[0,1,2] -> c[0,1,2]
```

So I use it to iterate this arrays.It will be `O(n)`,So it will faster than using `for` loop to iterate the arrays.Why?

**PS:I use Google translation to see those answer,so maybe I misunderstand it.**

Comment: `a[0,1,2] -> a[0,1,2] -> a[0,1,2]` - what does this mean?

Comment: I use a pointer which have the address of the next array to connect them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the mean of n in array? (Does it means the size of the array or the dimension of the array?)What's the time complexity of use for loop to iterate 2D array. Is it O(n) or O(n^2)?

You are exactly correct. This is a matter of convention. It is important what `n` denotes in a particular problem.

In case our array is `arr[n][n]`, iteration takes `O(n^2)` time. In case our array is `arr[k][k]` and `n=k*k` is the size of the array, iteration takes `O(n)` time. There is no contradiction here since we defined `n` differently in those cases.

Generally, if you only access an array element once, it is said that you have a linear complexity. No matter how you express this with the `O` notation.

Comment: If I have three *special* arrays,each array has the address of next array.(Think it as a ``Linked List``),So now If I iterate it,the time complexity will be `O(n)`,right?So does this faster than a normal 3D array?

Comment: again, suppose you have array AddrArray of size N so there will be N iteration , now if each of the arrays to whose address the AddrArray points to have equal size M then the total time complexity is of the order N*M. You need to ask first question or understand from the context "what is N (or M or K...)?". then the resultant time complexity will make sense.

Answer (score 2):

The complexity for the nested for loop is indeed n^2 and not n.  n in array there is the size.

Maybe something to think about to help you:  Consider if we needed to iterate over two different arrays in a similar manner and the arrays have different sizes of m and n, e.g.

```
for (int i = 1; i <=n; i += c) {
   for (int j = 1; j <=m; j += c) {
      // some O(1) expressions
   }
}
```

This would be O(m*n).  The case you're asking about is a specialization of this.

Answer (score 1):

For a 4x4 2D array manipulation if your *input* was only 4 it would be of exponential complexity. If you're input was all 16 numbers then it's linear. It all comes down to what you're passing in.

In your example if `n` is your input size then the fact you have a nested iteration makes it O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

First of all for the question to be answered is "what is n ?".

If you have input a 3x3 array.So you need to input 9 numbers.It need 9 times to iterate.
If you have input a 4x4 array.So you need to input 16 numbers.It need 16 times to iterate

Now if n = 3 & 4 for above two cases respectively then time to iterate is proportional to n square. If n = 9 & 16 for the above cases respectively then it is proportional to n.

Now coming to nested loops.

For an array of size [ROW][COL]

```
for (int r= 0; r < ROW; r++){ //outer loop
    for(int c= 0; c<COL; c++){ // inner loop
        //process array[r][c]
    }
}
```

For each iteration of outer loop , we have COL iterations of inner loop. Outer loop iterates for ROW number of times , hence time complexity is of the order ROW multiplied by COL.

Hope this helps.