# What's the input space and auxiliary space in this code block?

Tags: java, time-complexity, space-complexity

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int n;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    n=in.nextInt();
    int[] arr = new int[n];
    for(int i=0; i<=n; i++){
        arr[i]=i*2;
    }
}
```

I'm just confused about what is the **input** in space or time complexity.

Comment: This is a strange example, technically the space and time complexity of the main method is `O(1)` because `n=5`. If you were to create a new method, `foo(int n)`, that would change because there is actually an input.

Comment: @Clashsoft modified the code a bit. what is the auxiliary and input space here then?

Comment: How much input are you giving the code? Only the value `n`, so input space is _O(1)_. --- How much space does the code use? The array `arr`, so auxiliary space is _O(n)_, resulting in a space complexity of _O(n)_. --- How much time is used? Iterating the array once, so time complexity is _O(n)_.

Comment: *FYI:* Code will fail. Change `i<=n` to `i<n`.

Comment: @Andreas could you give a detailed answer to the modified question? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60846485/11811255

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA nah, didn't help!

Comment: Firstly, Your code is incomplete. The mentioned answer:  **This is a matter of convention. It is important what n denotes in a particular problem.**. In one word, people could define the mean of `N` by himself.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA please consider 'n' as a user input integer.